# R: How do I retain the time index when running na.spline() on a timeSeries object?

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

When creating a timeSeries object with missing values and replacing the NA through the `na.spline()` function the result becomes a data structure that has no time index any more. How can this be corrected?

Assume a timeSeries object such as:

```
# Some data setup
Lines.x <- '"1987-01-01"   7.1    NA   3
"1987-01-02"   5.2    5    2
"1987-01-06"   2.3    NA   9'
Lines.y <- '"1987-01-01"   55.3   66   45
"1987-01-03"   77.3   87   34'

# Create timeSeries object
x <- read.zoo(text = Lines.x)
y <- read.zoo(text = Lines.y)
z <- as.timeSeries(merge(x,  y))
```

z is a proper timeSeries object:

```
str(z)

Time Series:          
 Name:               object
Data Matrix:        
 Dimension:          4 6
 Column Names:       V2.x V3.x V4.x V2.y V3.y V4.y
 Row Names:          1987-01-01  ...  1987-01-06
Positions:          
 Start:              1987-01-01
 End:                1987-01-06
With:               
 Format:             %Y-%m-%d
 FinCenter:          GMT
 Units:              V2.x V3.x V4.x V2.y V3.y V4.y
 Title:              Time Series Object
 Documentation:      Tue Nov  4 19:09:43 2014

head(z)

GMT
           V2.x V3.x V4.x V2.y V3.y V4.y
1987-01-01  7.1   NA    3 55.3   66   45
1987-01-02  5.2    5    2   NA   NA   NA
1987-01-03   NA   NA   NA 77.3   87   34
1987-01-06  2.3   NA    9   NA   NA   NA
```

But when I run `Q <- na.spline(z)` the result is missing the time information.

```
str(Q)
 num [1:4, 1:6] 7.1 5.2 3.6 2.3 5 5 5 5 3 2 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "V2.x" "V3.x" "V4.x" "V2.y" ...

head(Q)
     V2.x V3.x V4.x V2.y V3.y V4.y
[1,]  7.1    5    3 55.3 66.0 45.0
[2,]  5.2    5    2 66.3 76.5 39.5
[3,]  3.6    5    4 77.3 87.0 34.0
[4,]  2.3    5    9 88.3 97.5 28.5
```

How can the loss or disturbance of the time index be avoided?

EDIT: To add further excitement, the following sequence of commands retains at least some time index in a zoo object (but only if the `as.zoo()` is the outer conversion):

```
Q <- as.zoo(as.timeSeries(z))
Q <- na.spline(Q)
```

Comment: `na.spline` has `zoo`, `zooreg` and `default` methods so if the default method does not work on a particular class then you will have to write your own method or use one of the supported classes.  e.g. `z0 <- merge(x, y); na.spline(z0)` Note that if the reason you want `timeSeries` class is for the `timeDate` class index then you could define a zoo series with `timeDate` index and use that instead. For example, this works:  `z <- aggregate(z0, as.timeDate, identity); na.spline(z)`

Comment: Thank you, I settled to write my own function. I have just been misled because na.omit() works well. I guess the reason is that the object is not changed when na.omit() is called in contract to na.spline().